# Flex items like pyramids

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I would like to know if there's any way I can align elements from the back. I know `wrap-reverse` reverses aligns elements from the back but it also inverts the ordering of the elements. Is it possible to start wrapping from the end and keeping the order the same. [Sample Image is posted here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThWTg.jpg)

Comment: it shoud  probably about a float missing, please edit and format your question according to [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From where I see it, this problem should not be solved by `CSS`, but by app logic, as it boils down to a reversed query (order of elements). Once you got them in reverse order, you can simply go

```
flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
```

... to align them in the bottom right corner. However, even though a bit cumbersome, `CSS` can, these days, reverse the order of your stack but, as far as I know, it requires one line / position. Here's an example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  max-width: calc(33.3333% - 2rem);
  min-width: calc(33.3333% - 2rem);

}
span:nth-child(1) {order: 5}
span:nth-child(2) {order: 4}
span:nth-child(3) {order: 3}
span:nth-child(4) {order: 2}
span:nth-child(5) {order: 1}

body {margin: 0;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

However, with a simple line of `JavaScript`, you could just reverse the order of all children in a parent on page load and I believe that is a lot more scalable when dealing with variable content/stacks.

But, then again, we get to the start of the answer: why not do it server-side?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did think about it but it's just a long process. I was wishing or a smaller answer.

Answer (score 0):

use  this css code :

```
div{flex-direction:row-reverse;}
```

The flex-direction may be column-reverse depending upon your layout

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does not help with the ordering, though. 321 is changed to 312 in the above image.